# Where can I get the getfileversion package?

Tags: packages, ctan

At the urls given in

http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg04518.html

I cannot find the `getfileversion` package. (Using a popular search engine did not help either.) Where (and why) is the package hiding?

Comment: The first time I tried I found it: just `google` for `tex latex getfileversion` and it will be on the top of your list.

Comment: Somewhere on the top of my list is `ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/getfileversion.html`. It's at number three in my case....

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Yes, but all links there to the actual files are just dead. That is probably because it is now named `latexfileversion`, as noted in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The README for [`latexfileversion`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexfileversion) says:

> Before version 0.3, this tool used to be named getfileversion.

Unless you need the old version for some reason, this is what you’re looking for.

Comment: I do not need the old version - `latexfileversion` is indeed what I was looking for! Thank you, +1, and accepted!

Answer (score 2):

You can find it [Here](http://200.144.190.125/CTAN//support/getfileversion/getfileversion)

Comment: No readme but at the beginning of the script you have a little description.

Comment: IP of a site but it's strange that getfileversion is not on a ctan server.

Comment: "The connection has timed out The server at 200.144.190.125 is taking too long to respond."